# Maximum Length for Custom AD Schema Attribute Names

Tags: active-directory

We are looking to add custom attributes to the User class in our AD schema and I cannot find anything regarding a length limit for the actual attribute name, only general limits to their values. Are there specific concerns with adding longer attribute names to classes in AD?

For example, is adding the attribute **Organization_DateTime_NewOfficeMoveDate** ok, or should it just be **Org_OfficeMoveDate**? Do the limits apply universally across domain/forest functional levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is 64 characters.

I attempted to add the following attributes to my test environment and received a warning that the name was already in use when I attempted to add the second one. There was no indication from the GUI that when I tried to add the first attribute it truncated the name, however that could've just been because I pasted in the name and didn't notice. Only after refreshing the console did I notice.

```
ThisIsAVeryVeryLongPropertyNameThatIHopeWillNotCauseErrorsInMyTestEnvironmentWhenIAttempToAddItToMyActiveDirectorySchemaAndThenAttachItToTheUserClass
```

and

```
ThisIsAVeryVeryLongPropertyNameThatIHopeWillNotCauseErrorsInMyTestEnvironmentWhenIAttempToAddItToMyActiveDirectorySchemaAndThenAttachItToTheUserClassThisIsAnEvenLongerOneThatShouldBeLongerThanTwoHundredAndFiftySixCharactersToSeeIfItCrossesThatBinaryBoundary
```

It was truncated to:

```
ThisIsAVeryVeryLongPropertyNameThatIHopeWillNotCauseErrorsInMyTe
```